# Can't load the View in Codeigniter when using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem loading the `View` from the `Controller`. I don't know why but I think my code is correct.

First, I have First `View` with an `AJAX` to `POST the text of input field`.

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
   New JONumber for <b><span id="new_project_name"></span></b> is <b><span id="new_jo"> </span></b>.
</div>

$("#view").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url('generator/view_generate')?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        name: $('#name').text()
              },
        success: function(){
        }
        });
});
```

And then it will pass the data to the `Controller`.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('generator_models');
    }
public function view_generate()
{
    $name    =   $this->input->post('name');

    $view_generated = $this->generator_models->view_generate($name);
    $this->view_name($view_generated);
}
public function view_name($view_generated)
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('name_views', $view_generated);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And this is my `Model`:

```
function view_generate($name)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

This is my Second `View`. This is different `View` file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="search-form" role="form" method="post">
<?php
    $view_name = $name;
    $view_id = $id;
?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label emp">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $view_jo_number; ?>"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id" class="col-sm-2 control-label emp">ID</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="id" placeholder="ID" name="id" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $view_project_name; ?>"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

After it gather data from the model it will proceed to the function (`$this->view_name($view_generated);`) to call the `View`.
Actually it work when I inspect element-->html in the Firefox but in the browser page it not proceed to the `View` page.
I don't know if it has something wrong with the AJAX, should I call the `controller in success` or there's really something wrong with my code?

Comment: I edited again the code. I have 2 Views. First is that I have an AJAX that will pass through the Controller. Then in the First Controller it will get data in the Model then go to the Second Controller. And in the Second Controller it will call the Second View.

Comment: where do you load generator_models ?

Comment: In the controller. I put the code above.

Comment: Is it possible in AJAX success that it will call the another method in controller? Like Example AJAX url it will call view_generate_jo_number() then in success it will call view_jo_number() then in view_jo_number() I will get the $view_generated from view_generate_jo_number() so that I will use the variable value in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure on what you're asking but If you want to load in a view through javascript this is how you do it: contents is the ID of the DIV that will be populated with the data(in your case your view).

```
$("#view").click(function()
var name = $('#name').text();
 $("#contents").load('<?php echo base_url('generator/view_generate/')?>'+name,
      function() {
        //console.log('success');   

    });
```

Comment: In my AJAX..in success I will get the variable value in controller. Then I will go to another url in controller and pass that variable value to another method in controller.